# Hide row if it is not on the first page

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, rdl, report-viewer2010

I want to hide a row of a table if it is not rendered on the first page of a report. The table (tablix) is in the header nor in the footer area.

I have tried to set an expression for the RowVisibility-property, something like:

```
(hidden) =Globals!PageNumber<>1
```

however, this leads to an exception saying that the PageNumber can only be used from within the header or the footer area.

Is there a possibility to check (in an expression) if an element is located on the first page of a report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a precise answer to my question, but maybe it helps someone with a similar issue:

- For the tablix activate the repeat row header option
- In the advance row group options, activate the option RepeatOnNewPage
- For the rows that should not be shown on the next page, disable the option KeepWithGroup

I don't understand why I can not set RepeatOnNewPage only for some but not for all rows, but with the KeepWithGroup option, it seems to work like I desired.

*If someone has a more precise answer to my original question, please post it. I will the change the accept to your answer!*

Answer (score 0):

Set this in the visibility property and the row will rendered or not depeding of the YourDatasetField value.

```
=IIF(True = Fields!YourDatasetField.Value, False, True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but hiding the row based on a field was not the issue. The problem was the internal variable PageNumber that is not usable from within the content-block.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to hide just one field in the header on the first page. May not be exact but worked for me.

```
=IIF(Globals!PageNumber = 1, True, False)
```